# Typescript: generic type instanceof

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I hope this question is something achievable since the nature of Typescript (i.e. being transalted to JS) makes me wonder it..

So suppose I have these classes:

```
class Animal{}
class Musquito extends Animal {}
class Dog extends Animal {}


const lst: Animal[] = [new Musquito(), new Dog()];
```

I would now like to write an extension method on `Array` to return only those elements of a specific type such that i can do

```
const dogs = lst.ofType<Dog>(); // dogs would then be of type Dog[], NOT Animal[]
```

But I am stuck with this extension method

```
interface Array<T> {
  ofType<T2>() : T2[];
}

Array.prototype.ofType = function <T2>(): T2[] {
  return this.filter((x) => x instanceof T2) as T2[];
};
```

The above implementation does not compile.

> 'T2' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here

Is there a way for me to extract only those elements which are of type `T2` to return it as such an array?

Comment: Note that extending native prototypes with nonstandard methods is considered bad practice, but that's up to you.  Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mpLdzm) meet your needs?  If so I could write up an answer.  If not, what am I missing?  (If you reply to me please say @jcalz or I will not be notified)

Comment: Thanks! Both your answers are indeed the method that I am looking for. Just out of curisousity, why is writing extensions methods in TS a bad practice?